# How can I show the image as progress bar in android

Tags: android

Can I show the image as progress bar in android like the attached image [image: Progress bar image expected]

Comment: that means you want to use that image instaed of progress bar? then create a `custom dialog` put that image in that dialog and display that dialog in place of progress bar

Comment: check this library out, might help https://github.com/mrwonderman/android-square-progressbar

Comment: Then how can I fill the progress color as I expected in the image

Comment: @KaranMer give you link to nice library, which can be useful, take a look on it. Where do you exactly stuck right now ?

Comment: you can check how to use it. at least g0 through the page first. spoon feeding ain't allowed

Answer (score 0):

This might be some difficult solution as you need more images for different states of your progress image, but it is working for me .

create anim_img.xml in drawable folder like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/img1"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/img_01"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/img_02"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/img_03"
    android:duration="200"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/img_04"
    android:duration="200"/>

</animation-list>
```

In your activity/fragment, keep below code

```
ImageView animimg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.animimg);
animimg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anim_img);

AnimationDrawable anim_draw = (AnimationDrawable) animimg
            .getBackground();
anim_draw.start();
```